# JSON Format HTML text from single line of text column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, json-formatting

In SPO list we have a single line of text, where values are sent as anchor tag
e.g `<a href="https://SPSITE.sharepoint.com/sites/inspection/Shared Documents/Plant & Equipment/MAINTENANCE/Maintenance Program/Inspection_Vehicle_18082022_075430__3.pdf">Inspection_Vehicle_18082022_075430__3.pdf </a>`

WE do not have control on the program that sets this value.

Is there way we can format this with JSON to show as [Inspection_Vehicle_18082022_075430__3.pdf](https://SPSITE.sharepoint.com/sites/inspection/Shared%20Documents/Plant%20&%20Equipment/MAINTENANCE/Maintenance%20Program/Inspection_Vehicle_18082022_075430__3.pdf) inside list?

Basically to rend this text as HTML ? All json format take "txtContent" as parameter. or they need elmType.

or is there a way to do string manipulation?

We are avoiding having another power automate to do string manipulation and extract HREF/Filename value.

Comment: There are few [operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#operators) available for string manipulation like substring, indexOf. Check the link for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values always follow the same format, then you can extract the values and build a clickable link using this JSON (Column Settings > Format this column > Advanced Mode and then paste the below code):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "=substring(@currentField, indexOf(@currentField, '>') + 1, indexOf(@currentField, '</'))",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=substring(@currentField, indexOf(@currentField, 'href=') + 6, indexOf(@currentField, '>')-1)"
  }
}
```